# Load array from remote server in android studio

Tags: php, android, arrays

I am new in android studio
Currently I am working with android project where dynamic image is loading from remote server. I done it with static array. but I want to get these array from remote page. here is the static array

```
String[] itemTitle =
            {
            "1st Title",
            "2nd Title",
            "3rd Title",
            "4th Title"
            };

    String[] itemDate =
            {
                    "11 Sept 17",
                    "21 Sept 17",
                    "12 Sept 17",
                    "21 Sept 17"
            };
    String[] thumb =
            {
                    "1st Thumb",
                    "2nd Thumb",
                    "3rd Thumb",
                    "4th Thumb"
            };
```

Now I want to load these array from remote server http://www.example.com/getArray.php
I already made the php file. but how to get the array from the remote url from android studio?

But I can't understand what to do?

Comment: Try using json_encode() in PHP to echo the array. Then decode JSON on your andorid code.

Comment: In my openion you should create a REST api and send these data in JSON format so that your android app can parse the data.

Comment: @natheriel its not duplicate as you said. your suggested article is about PHP. But i want to get it in android studio

Comment: well, in this case have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android. If you return JSON at your getArray.php location, then you could use the answer and info from that question to read your JSON for future use.

Answer (score 1):

Check this tutorial this explain how can you create REST api in PHP
[How to create REST API in PHP](https://www.codeofaninja.com/2017/02/create-simple-rest-api-in-php.html)

After creating you can parse these arrays one by one in your android project.

Comment: I said i already created the php page with array but I want to get the array from the PHP file to android studio

Comment: You have to create REST api first and then you can call that api using volley  and then you can parse that array in your android project.

Comment: Means you have encode your array in json and after that you can use it in android project

Comment: If you done that use https://www.itsalif.info/content/android-volley-tutorial-http-get-post-put Volley to get your array from server and parse it.